# How to create an array of variables Arduino

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, arduino

How would i go about creating an array of variables such as.....

```
int incColor, c0, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 = 0;
int circleArray[11][9] = { {c5, c5, c5, c5, c5, c5, c5, c5, c5}, 
                             {c4, c4, c4, c4, c4, c4, c4, c4, c4}, 
                             {c4, c3, c3, c3, c3, c3, c3, c3, c4}, 
                             {c4, c3, c2, c2, c2, c2, c2, c3, c4}, 
                             {c4, c3, c2, c1, c1, c1, c2, c3, c4}, 
                             {c4, c3, c2, c1, c0, c1, c2, c3, c4}, 
                             {c4, c3, c2, c1, c1, c1, c2, c3, c4}, 
                             {c4, c3, c2, c2, c2, c2, c2, c3, c4}, 
                             {c4, c3, c3, c3, c3, c3, c3, c3, c4}, 
                             {c4, c4, c4, c4, c4, c4, c4, c4, c4}, 
                             {c5, c5, c5, c5, c5, c5, c5, c5, c5} };
```

So that later on in the code i will be able to address them like this...

```
void circle(uint16_t mode) 
{
  switch (mode)
  {
     case 0:
     c0 = random(255);
     break; 
     case 1:
     c0 = incColor;
     incColor++;
     break;
  }
  for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++)
  {
     for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
    {
       strip.setPixelColor(x, y, Wheel(circleArray[x][y]));
    } 
  }
  c5 = c4;
  c4 = c3;
  c3 = c2;
  c2 = c1;
  c1 = c0;

}
```

The code above doesnt work, i tested both c5 and circleArray[0][0]

```
c5 = 34
circleArray[0][0] = 0
```

circleArray[0][0] should be the same as c5 is what i thought but for some reason the value is not getting set...

Does anybody know what im doing wrong here?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~EDIT~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Fixed!! thanks to @sj0h for helping me see a much easier solution so now i can turn this...

```
int c[6] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};    
int  circleArray[11][9] = {  {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5},
                             {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, 
                             {4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4}, 
                             {4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4}, 
                             {4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4}, 
                             {4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, 
                             {4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4}, 
                             {4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4}, 
                             {4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4}, 
                             {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}, 
                             {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5} };

void circle(uint16_t mode) 
{
  switch (mode)
  {
     case 0:
     c[0] = random(255);
     break; 
     case 1:
     c[0] = incColor;
     incColor++;
     break;
  }
  for (int x = 0; x < 11; x++)
  {
     for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
    {
       strip.setPixelColor(x, y, Wheel(c[circleArray[x][y]]));
    } 
  }
  c[5] = c[4];
  c[4] = c[3];
  c[3] = c[2];
  c[2] = c[1];
  c[1] = c[0];

}
```

into the real life application....

[image: www.famousmods.com for more info]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

References may do what you want:

```
int &circleArray[11][9] = ......
```

This will make circleArray an array of references rather than copied values.

---

**Edit:** above isn't supported by the standard, and support is compiler dependent.

Using pointers instead, you would have

```
int *circleArray[11][9] = {{&c5, &c5, .....
```

and then change all the circleArray acceses to be *circleArray[x][y] instead of circleArray[x][y].

---

A different approach, which may be more versatile, would be to keep colour array indices in circleArray:

```
int incColor;
int cn[6] = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
int circleArray[11][9] = { {5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5},
                           {4,4 .....
```

Then c0 would become c[0] and you would access the array value like

```
cn[circleArray[x][y]]
```

you could also make circleArray uint8_t to save some space, as all entries will fit inside a byte.

Comment: I tried this and *circleArray[11][9] and the error i got was    `C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino/Print.h:63: note:                 size_t Print::print(long unsigned int, int) <near match>`

Comment: If you use *circleArray[11][9] it will achieve a similar thing, but you will need to de-reference the pointer each time you access circleArray as a value, by putting the star out the front.  Where was the error when you used &circleArray ?

Comment: `Test1:8: error: declaration of 'circleArray' as array of references`    it wont let me verify the program, it crashes on the declaration of the array

Comment: Ok, so it seems that arrays of references are not supported by the C++ standard, but some compilers allow them.  In that case, you are back to pointers.  I'll edit the answer to show the pointer method.

Comment: Great Idea!!!!!!! what you described works so much easier than what i was attempting to do, thanks a ton!!! I'll edit my post to include a pic of what you helped me to do!

Comment: doing it that way may also help other code, like your series of assignments at the end can now be done in a for loop, ie for(int i=5;i>0;--i) c[i]=c[i-1];

Answer (score 0):

`circleArray[0][0]` won't be the same as `c5`, because on assignment a value is **copied** from one variable to another.

To alias one location to multiple variables, you should use pointers or references.